# Restart debugging Node.js only after TSLint and TypeScript compilation are successful

Tags: node.js, typescript, nodemon, tslint

I am trying to write a npm debug script such that when any source file is changed, `tslint` is executed, followed by `tsc` and finally `node --inspect`.

Currently, I have the following scripts in `package.json`:

```
"start": "node dist/app.js",
"start-debug": "node --inspect dist/app.js",
"build": "npm run tslint && npm run build-ts",
"tslint": "tslint -c tslint.json -p tsconfig.json",
"build-ts": "tsc",
"debug": "nodemon --exec \"(npm run build || exit 1) && npm run start-debug\""
```

The problem is that, when the lint process or compilation fails, the node.js instance is terminated. I would like to have the node.js instance restarted only when `tslint` and `tsc` exit successfully.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Does `"defaultSeverity": "warning"` in you `tslint.json` help?

Comment: The behavior of tslint is correct -- it is an error if the code doesn't conform to the lint configurations. What I want is that, if the new code is not compliable, the old (existing) complied code should continue to run.